# San lun wwid number 3 in front

Tags: linux, storage-area-network, scsi

I have a san lun in a linux server, using this following command I saw this:

```
 scsi_id -g -u -s /block/sda
 38001438005dea3760000700002660000     #3 number in front of wwid
 sg_inq -p 0x83 /dev/sda | grep "\[" 
 [8001438005dea3760000700002660000]
```

From san of view the wwid is 8001438005dea3760000700002660000, but the os add a 3 number in front.

What means the number 3 in the front of the wwid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://linux.die.net/man/8/scsi_id

> Identifiers based on page 0x83 are prefixed by the identifier type followed by the page 0x83 identifier. For example, a device with a NAA (Name Address Authority) type of 3 (also in this case the page 0x83 identifier starts with the NAA value of 6):

```
# /lib/udev/scsi_id --page=0x83 --whitelisted --device=/dev/sda
3600a0b80000b174b000000d63efc5c8c
```